# Forward volatility smile: Local Volatility vs Stochastic volatility

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility, local-volatility

I was reading this great answer: [What are the advantages/disadvantages of these approaches to deal with volatility surface?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/5981/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-these-approaches-to-deal-with-volatilit)

And I have the following question:

How to show that the forward volatility smile of Local Volatility flattens while the one from Stochastic Volatility does not?

Could you please provide a mathematical demonstration of this fact?

EDIT

[This answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/why-dynamics-of-local-volatility-is-wrong/17862#17862) answers my question. But in the following equation from the answer

$C(t,S;T\to T+\theta,K) := E^Q[(\frac{S_{T+\theta}}{S_{T}}-K)_+] =: C_{BS}(S=1,\theta,K;\Sigma(t,S;T\to T+\theta,K))$

I don't understand why the payoff of the forward start option is not rather

$ E^Q[(S_{T+\theta}-S_{T})_+] $

and why it is set $S=1$

Comment: Does [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/17862/54838) help?

Comment: @AKdemy thanks a lot! This helps a lot! But I still have an additional question, could you please have a look on the EDIT?

Comment: It's just a question of absolute forward start and relative forward start. Relative forward start are more appealing in general since they have nice homogeneity properties under log-space invariant diffusion models (like BS or most SV models). In other words, the last equality of the first equation you mention (especially the $S=1$ part and keeping the relative moneyness $K$) can only be written under a homogeneous model such as BS.